# Find div element and replace the value-innerhtml using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

Iam having the following table structure.

```
HTML:  
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <img id='imgScheduled' onclick='start();'/>
  </td>
  <td>
   <div class='divStatus'>Scheduled</div>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
..Same table structure repeated
```

The above table is defined dynamically where in the img ids are also generated dynamically. I would like to change the divStatus value on the click of img which has some functionality i.e status needs to be changed to "inprogress' using jquery just like $("#imgid").closest something, am not sure.

Comment: Do the `img` elements have a predictable pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind a click on your image, and find the .divStatus, then change its content !

Remember .text() will espace your argument, instead of .html() that will render DOM elements !

http://jsfiddle.net/XL5Ew/

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#imgScheduled', function (e) {
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.divStatus').text('in progress...');
        // Or with elements
        $(this).parent().parent().find('.divStatus').html($('<span>').text('in progress...'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Not for long I think :)

Comment: You're aware the `img` and `span` are in different parent elements, right?

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
$('body').on('click','td > img',function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').find('.divStatus').html('in progress..');
});
```

Comment: you can test it in fiddle

Comment: You're aware the `img` and `span` are in different parent elements, right?

Comment: I think closest('tr') is cleaner than parent().parent() in fact. Good job !

Comment: @flo you when you use parent its fine when someone else uses its not good approach LoL

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, the mistake in your answer wasn't with `parent.parent` It was with `live()`

Comment: I mostly use live so thats why I posted live but I updated with on as well

Comment: You can say I have become used to with live so I forget always to post with on in answers as I peraonaly use live

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I was not talking of parent().parent() but just parent() in itself. It is much more dependent of the DOM structure than closest(), and this is the reason why I made a small mistake at the beginning, so I think Amit's answer is better than mine, or yours too !
About .live(), you really should stop using it as it is officially deprecated for a while() !

Comment: I will try to use on from now.. :)